# ¿ Como detectar fines de semana con php?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de averiguar de un intervalo de fechas si se contiene dias que sean sabado o domingo, el codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
    $fecha_i = '02/03/2017';
    $fecha_f = '10/03/2017';

    $begin = new DateTime($fecha_i);
    $end = new DateTime($fecha_f);
    $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

    foreach($daterange as $date){

    print date('l', strtotime($date));
    if(date('l', strtotime($date)) == 'Sunday' || date('l', strtotime($date)) == 'Saturday'){
        print 'Fin de Semana: '.$date->format("d-m-Y")."<br>";
    } else {
        print 'Semana: '.$date->format("d-m-Y")."<br>"; 
    }
}
```

---

Resultado obtenido, no se porque los repite:

WednesdaySemana: 02-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 03-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 04-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 05-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 06-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 07-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 08-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 09-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 10-03-2017

Comment: ¿Y funciona o cual es resultado que estas obteniendo?

Comment: no funciona. el me esta repitiendo los dias. este es el resultado que obtengo.
WednesdaySemana: 02-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 03-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 04-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 05-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 06-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 07-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 08-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 09-03-2017
WednesdaySemana: 10-03-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $fecha_i = '02/03/2017';
    $fecha_f = '10/03/2017';

    $begin = new DateTime($fecha_i);
    $end = new DateTime($fecha_f);
    $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

    foreach($daterange as $date){

    if(date('l', strtotime($date->format("d-m-Y"))) == 'Sunday' || date('l', strtotime($date->format("d-m-Y"))) == 'Saturday'){
        print 'Fin de Semana: '.$date->format("d-m-Y")."<br>";
    } else {
        print 'Semana: '.$date->format("d-m-Y")."<br>"; 
    }
}
```

// Resultado

Semana: 02-03-2017
Semana: 03-03-2017
Fin de Semana: 04-03-2017
Fin de Semana: 05-03-2017
Semana: 06-03-2017
Semana: 07-03-2017
Semana: 08-03-2017
Semana: 09-03-2017
Semana: 10-03-2017

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso me dio problemas ese ejemplo, pues la función strtotime recibe el formato
'd-m-Y' pues si le pasas 'd/m/Y' no hace nada.

```
$fecha_i = '01-01-2021';
$fecha_f = '31-12-2021';

$begin = new DateTime($fecha_i);
$end = new DateTime($fecha_f);
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date)
{
    if(date('l', strtotime($date->format("d-m-Y"))) == 'Sunday' || date('l', strtotime($date->format("d-m-Y"))) == 'Saturday')
    {
        echo 'Fin de Semana: '.$date->format("d-m-Y")."<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Semana: '.$date->format("d-m-Y")."<br>"; 
    }
}
```

Gracias y espero les sirva saludos!!